# Is there any way to show 'download completed' notification using react-native?

Tags: react-native, download, notifications

[image]

Currently I'm dealing with file downloading function of react-native app.

What I'm wondering is how can I show 'Download completed' notification as shown in the image right after the file has downloaded at notification center.

RN Version : 0.61.5

Comment: I found an answer by myself.

Using download manager from rn-fetch-blob function would work.
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

But I'm using react-native-fs to download a file. Is there any other way to create a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://github.com/cjdell/react-native-fs-test/blob/master/index.common.js

```
const ret = RNFS.downloadFile({ fromUrl: url, toFile: downloadDest });  
ret.promise.then(res => {
   // Show Your Notification
}).catch(err => {});
```

for notification you can use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification, this is an example:

```
RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl,
    toFile,
}).promise.then((res) => {
    PushNotification.localNotification(details)
});
```

Comment: why would someone use push notification when there is built in notification for downloads.

Comment: At the time you are currently calling `PushNotification.localNotification(details)`, it is not sure that the download has completed. It is not even sure that there was a return status 200 from the remote host.

Comment: @jyotishmansaikia What do you mean? Does RNFS has that built in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RNFetchBlob package to download any file from the internet and configure the options to show notification, set notification : true,  to get the status of download whether complete or ongoing, (only Android), if you keep it false you need to add one more permission in the manifest, i.e DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION

```
let options = {
          fileCache: true,
          addAndroidDownloads : {
            useDownloadManager : true,
            notification : false,
            path:  PictureDir + "/image_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2)+".png",
            description : 'Image'
          }
        }
        config(options).fetch('GET', url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used RNFetchBlob to download image/pdf. This helped me to show download notification.

```
RNFetchBlob.android.addCompleteDownload({
                title: "QR Code Image",
                description: 'Download complete',
                mime: 'image/png',
                path: path,
                showNotification: true,
              })
```

for me its image file so mime type is "image/png" for pdf its "application/pdf"

Comment: is this android only ? and what about ios ?